# How to allow an object to remove itself from a LinkedList in Java?

Tags: java, list, reference, linked-list

**Main Question:**
I'm seeking some way to give an object within a LinkedList a reference to itself within the list so that it can (efficiently) remove itself from said list (Without sorting through the list looking for itself. I'd like it to just directly cut itself from the list and tie the previous and next items together.).

**Less Necessary Details:**
I've done a reasonable amount of googling and not found anything other than people advising not to use circular references.

I'd like to do this as I'm designing a game, and in the game objects can implement various interfaces which allow them to be in various lists which are looped through in a prioritized manner. A single object might be in a draw loop, a loop which steps it through the frames of its animation, a high priority logic loop, and a low priority logic loop all at the same time. I would like to implement a removeFrom|TypeOfLoop| method in each appropriate interface so that if an object decides that it no longer needs to be in a loop it can directly remove itself. This keeps the objects that do the actual looping pleasantly simple.

Alternatively, If there is no way to do this, I'm thinking of implementing a flagging system where the list checks to see if each item wants to be removed based on a variable within the item. However, I dislike the idea of doing this enough to possibly just make my own LinkedList that is capable of removing by reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did this recently. I was looking for an O(1) add O(1) remove lock-free `Collection`. Eventually I wrote my own `Ring` because I wanted a fixed-size container but you may find the technique I used for my first attempt of value.

I don't have the code in front of me but if memory serves:

Take a copy of [Doug Lea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doug_Lea)'s excellent [Concurrent Doubly LinkedList](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/ConcurrentDoublyLinkedList.htm) and:

1. Expose the `Node` class. I used an `interface` but that is up to you.
2. Change the `add`, `offer` ... methods to return a `Node` instead of `boolean`. *It is now no longer a java `Collection`, but see my comment later.*
3. <del>Expose the `delete` method of the `Node` class or</del> add a `remove` method that takes a `Node`.

You can now remove elements from the list in O(1) time, and it is **Lock Free**.

**Added**

Here's an implementation of the `remove(Node)` method taken from his `Iterator` implementation. Note that you have to keep trying until you succeed.

```
public void remove(Node<E> n) {
  while (!n.delete() && !n.isDeleted())
    ;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, so your object needs to keeps a reference to its own Node after it's added, I assume. It still introduces a circular reference, but indeed you get the O(1) deletion time.

I like!

Comment: You can keep it a `Collection` by adding your own `add` and `offer` methods that return a `Node` instead of hacking his. Perhaps `nAdd` and `nOffer`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your alternative is much better than letting the item remove itself from the loop. It reduces the responsibilities of the objects in the list, and avoids circular references.

Moreover, You could use Guava's [`Iterables.filter()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#filter%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29) method and iterate over a filtered list, rather than checking explicitely if the object should be rendered or not at each iteration.

Even if what you want to do was possible, you would get a ConcurrentModificationException when removing an object from the list while iterating on it. The only way to do that is to remove the current object from the iterator.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using LinkedList, there's no more efficient way to remove an item than to iterate over it and do iterator.remove() when you find your element.

If you're using google collections or guava, you can do it in a oneliner:

```
Iterables.removeIf(list.iterator(), Predicates.equalTo(this));
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be changing your algorithm to use Iterator to iterate over List objects and use Iterator.remove() method to remove current element.